# Facebook: Currently Ineligible for Submission due to missing translated strings

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, submission

I'm trying to support 2 languages in my game - English and Georgian. Facebook is asking me to enter the details for Georgian but there is no field or anything for Georgian details (there is only for English). Where should I enter details for another language?

[image: Facebook: Currently Ineligible for Submission]

thank you

Comment: Are you able to set the translated strings in the 'Localize' tab on the left?

Comment: I'm an idiot.
thanks mate, that did it

Comment: no problem, it really should link there!